# Extend dictionary when Value has associated type

Tags: swift

Consider the following:

```
struct Weak<Object: AnyObject> {

    weak var object: Object?
}

class ConcreteClass { }

extension Dictionary where Value == Weak<AnyObject> {

    func foo() {
        print("Success!")
    }
}

var dict: [String: Weak<ConcreteClass>] = [:]
```

Now, the next line won't compile

```
dict.foo()  //  Referencing instance method 'foo()' on 'Dictionary' requires the types 'Weak<ConcreteClass>' and 'Weak<AnyObject>' be equivalent
```

Is there a way to tell the extension that `Weak.Object` doesn't matter for `foo()` to do it's job?

Comment: There is no substitution principle for generics based on their parameterized types. They are not covariant. Maybe ConcreteClass is an AnyObject but still you cannot use `Weak<ConcreteClass>` where `Weak<AnyObject>` is expected. They are unrelated types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after tinkering a bit, I found a solution that does the trick:

```
extension Dictionary {

    func foo<T: AnyObject>() where Value == Weak<T> {
        print("success")
    }
}
```

This does exactly what I needed without any protocols (as @bscothern suggested).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `Weak<AnyObject>` is a concrete type that you can create an instance of that is different than a `Weak<ConcreteClass>`. You need to express the relationship through an `assoicatedtype` on a protocol.

You can adjust your code like this to achieve the desired result:

```swift
protocol WeakProtocol {
    associatedtype Object: AnyObject
    var object: Object? { get } // Also add set if you decide it is appropriate
}

struct Weak<Object: AnyObject>: WeakProtocol {
    weak var object: Object?
}

class ConcreteClass { }

extension Dictionary where Value: WeakProtocol {
    func foo() {
        print("Success!")
    }
}

var dict: [String: Weak<ConcreteClass>] = [:]

dict.foo()
```

The downsides of this approach are that you must expose the protocol that essentially duplicates the struct.

Answer (score 0):

Swift’s generics are invariant, which states that just because a generic type wraps a subclass, it does not make it a subtype of a generic wrapping its superclass. You can't write like this:

```
struct Generic<T> {}
class Parent {}
class Child: Parent {}

func foo(generic: Generic<Parent>) {}

let childGeneric = Generic<Child>()
foo(generic: childGeneric) //Cannot convert value of type 'Generic<Child>' to expected argument type 'Generic<Parent>'
```

But Swift’s built-in generic types are covariant, which means that generic types can be subtypes of other generic types. For example, this is correct:

```
class Parent {}
class Child: Parent {}

func foo(generic: Array<Parent>) {}

let childGeneric = Array<Child>()
foo(generic: childGeneric)
```

Comment: I've provided a code snippet for my problem using your explanation. Thanks =)